# javascript test if any of two flags are present

Tags: javascript, operators, bit, flags

I have this simple code:

```
var A = 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8;

var x = 4;
```

Is there a equivalent of this code:

```
if(x == C || x == D){

}
```

but using just just the bit operator thing (a single condition)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test the combination of C and D:

```
if (x & (C | D))
```

The result will be non-zero when any of the bits set in C or D are also set in x.